# Change Digitally signed by "Key Owner Name"

Tags: java, itext

I'm signing a pdf with itext5

```
MakeSignature.signDetached(appearance, digest, pks, chain, crlList, ocspClient, tsaClient, estimatedSize, subfilter);
```

The generated text is: Digitally signed by JOHN MORGAN + Timestamp

when I edit the Layer2Text

```
appearance.setLayer2Text("Signed by ");
```

I get only: Signed by (without name).

I need to edit "Digitally signed by" but i want to keep the name of the key owner

How can I get the name of the key's owner ?

I tried using the alias (used to get the key from the keystore) but it's not the correct name (contain special characters)

```
KeyStore keyStore = .....;
PrivateKey pk = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(alias, null);
```

Thank you

Comment: If you set the layer 2 text, you have to set the whole level 2 text, i.e. not only `"Signed by "` but `"Signed by JOHN MORGAN + Timestamp"`.

Comment: Yes that is it

How can I get the name of the token owner ?

Comment: @mkl (I edit the main post)

I tried using the alias (used to get the key from the keystore) but it's not the correct name (contain special characters)

Comment: Use the information from the signing certificate, e.g. as explained in my answer.

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the layer 2 text, you have to set the *whole* layer 2 text, i.e. not only `"Signed by "` but `"Signed by JOHN MORGAN + Timestamp"`.

As iText is open source, you can simply copy&paste and manipulate iText code for generating the layer 2 text. The iText code responsible:

```
String text;
if (layer2Text == null) {
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
    buf.append("Digitally signed by ");
    String name = null;
    X500Name x500name = CertificateInfo.getSubjectFields((X509Certificate)signCertificate);
    if (x500name != null) {
        name = x500name.getField("CN");
        if (name == null)
            name = x500name.getField("E");
    }
    if (name == null)
        name = "";
    buf.append(name).append('\n');
    SimpleDateFormat sd = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss z");
    buf.append("Date: ").append(sd.format(signDate.getTime()));
    if (reason != null)
        buf.append('\n').append(reasonCaption).append(reason);
    if (location != null)
        buf.append('\n').append(locationCaption).append(location);
    text = buf.toString();
}
else
    text = layer2Text;
```

*(from `PdfSignatureAppearance.getAppearance()`)*

Replacing references to protected members by getters and constants and removing `"Digitally "` from this code results in something you can use for your task:

```
StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
buf.append("Signed by ");
String name = null;
X500Name x500name = CertificateInfo.getSubjectFields((X509Certificate)chain[0]);
if (x500name != null) {
    name = x500name.getField("CN");
    if (name == null)
        name = x500name.getField("E");
}
if (name == null)
    name = "";
buf.append(name).append('\n');
SimpleDateFormat sd = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss z");
buf.append("Date: ").append(sd.format(appearance.getSignDate().getTime()));
if (appearance.getReason() != null)
    buf.append('\n').append("Reason: ").append(appearance.getReason());
if (appearance.getLocation() != null)
    buf.append('\n').append("Location: ").append(appearance.getLocation());
appearance.setLayer2Text(buf.toString());
```

*(from [CreateSignature](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/signature/CreateSignature.java#L664) test `signWithCustomLayer2Text`)*